# maximum number of automatic posts to page allowed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spam, facebook-page

I have an app where a user can enter a message in our CMS and select a list of pages where it should be posted to. The pages are all company pages (local branches of the company) and I have the page access token.

Is there a hard limit in how many posts I can send out?

Is there a difference if I send out all posts at once or if I put in a delay in between posts?

Answer (score 2):

The limit is flexible.  It is based on Facebook's complex algorithms on how naughty/nice your app is.  There is no hard answer for you.  Just monitor the exceptions coming back from the API and follow what they tell you when you do get one.

Answer (score 0):

[FB Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#thingstoknow)

`If you exceed 5M MAU, 100M API calls per day, or 50M impressions per day, you may be subject to additional terms.`